# How to remove the id from the end of the filename before uploading in AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, strapi

I'm using strapi and using AWS S3 as file upload provider.

My `config/plugins.js` :

```
upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "aws-s3",
      providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: env("S3_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
        secretAccessKey: env("S3_AWS_ACCESS_SECRET"),
        region: env("S3_AWS_REGION"),
        params: {
          Bucket: env("S3_AWS_BUCKET"),
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, when a file is uploaded the url looks like this:

https://domain-strapi-assets.s3.region.amazonaws.com/dev_article_dummy_6d77795a47

Which is
domain.com/filename_id.jpg

**What I'm looking for is** 
domain.com/filename.jpg (without the id)

So, the ideal URL will look like this 
https://domain-strapi-assets.s3.region.amazonaws.com/dev_article_dummy

What I've tried to do is pass the `Key` to the params but of no use:

```
params: {
          Bucket: env("S3_AWS_BUCKET"),
          Key:'somenamehere'
        }
```

Comment: You will probably need to pass it when uploading, can you please share your code that actually does the upload? That config is for the S3 client - filenames / object keys are not set at that level but are set at a lower, per-request level.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary that's what exactly is wrong with strapi, it doesn't provide you the AWS S3 code in the src but instead it just asks you for these options and it'll take care of the rest itself. All of this is very cool until you want to make some modifications!

Comment: Where is your code that actually uploads an object? there must be some way to say upload this.